# Interactively run script blocs in IPython

Tags: ipython

Working with terminals only, is there a way to select script blocs by line ranges and run them in IPython?

Something like `%run -r 35-48 thescript.py`?

I understand that `ipython -i`, `%edit` and `%loadpy` offer ways to run scripts interactively, but I'd like to progress through the script without loading it upfront, in other words, have the namespace built as I progress through the script, bloc by bloc.

For example, I'd have one terminal with the script open in vim & `set number`, tweak & save as needed, and on the other terminal I'd run ipython from which I'd select line ranges to run (and build the namespace as I go along).

Comment: From your description of what you'd like to do, [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks, this does look like what I was looking for. I've installed vim-ipython, but keep getting `E21: Cannot make changes, 'Modifiable' is off` when I `ctrl-s` a line, even after setting `set modifiable`. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer to the question is "No":

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2011-December/008796.html